# Is Plants vs Zombies 2 supported on the Nexus 7?

Tags: android, plants-vs-zombies-2

I bought a Nexus 7 with LTE unlocked from the US Google Play store and I later added a T-Mobile data only sim card to the device.

When I checked for PvZ2 on the play store it was not there. When I checked it on the google play website it said that "This app is incompatible with all your devices"

When I clicked Install, under Choose Your Device, it said, "This item cannot be installed in your device's country" which is absurd. I bought this device in America with the US Google Play Store and an American phone company's sim card is in the thing.

Can anyone assist me?

Comment: You should contact EA and find out why

Comment: It is already out for Android. You may want to take a look at this article:
[http://www.gottabemobile.com/2013/10/24/plants-vs-zombies-2-now-available-android/](http://bluefirecontentnetwork.yzi.me/gottabemobile-plants-vs-zombies-2-now-available-android/)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a truly "too localised" problem (being unable to install because it hadn't been released yet in the US).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to EA, the game is available only in Australia and New Zealand, at least for now. A full international release is scheduled to happen soon, but no date, or week, has been mentioned.

Some people have mentioned this following article as a workaround though. I cannot be sure if this works or not but you can give it a try.

http://www.panama-technology.net/download-region-restricted-google-play-apps-draft/

Sources

http://androidcommunity.com/plants-vs-zombies-2-is-on-your-google-play-store-in-selected-countries-only-20131003/

This article was published on Oct 3, 2013.

http://news.softpedia.com/news/Plants-vs-Zombies-2-for-Android-Now-Available-for-Download-in-Some-Countries-392432.shtml

This article was published on Oct 18, 2013.

Comment: Thanks, now that I know what the problem is, I feel okay waiting. I'll use the [Chinese Version](http://as.baidu.com/a/item?docid=4249303) to tide me over